# Vue.js can't receive correct return value from POST function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I would like to receive the full data like below which is what I send to backend

```
{
  _id: 64a8a8e9903039edb52ccc4c,
  productName: 'Vial 2ml(US) Type1',
  OracleItemNum: 8110000008,
  batchSize: 823248,
  numCntrRecv: 11,
  aqlLevel: 'II',
  createdDate: 2023-07-08T00:08:09.288Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The database save what I send after I post it from frontend. The question is I didn't received it after I post it from the frontend vue.js.
My frontend service function is like below:

```
function addNewSample(sample){
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{ 
            ...authHeader(),
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(sample)
    };
    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/samples/newAdd`, requestOptions).then((response) => {console.log(response)});
}
```

The response I received in the console is like below:

```
body: ReadableStream
locked: false
[[Prototype]]: ReadableStream
cancel: ƒ cancel()
getReader: ƒ getReader()
locked: (...)
pipeThrough: ƒ pipeThrough()
pipeTo: ƒ pipeTo()
tee: ƒ tee()
constructor: ƒ ReadableStream()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ReadableStream"
get locked: ƒ locked()
[[Prototype]]: Object
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
[[Prototype]]: Headers
append: ƒ append()
delete: ƒ delete()
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
get: ƒ ()
getSetCookie: ƒ getSetCookie()
has: ƒ has()
keys: ƒ keys()
set: ƒ ()
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ Headers()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Headers"
[[Prototype]]: Object
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:4000/samples/newAdd"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

In the backend node.js side, my controller file is like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const sampleService = require('./sample.service');

//routes
router.post('/newAdd', addSample);
//router.get('/:id', getById);

module.exports = router

function addSample(req, res, next){
    sampleService.create(req.body)
    .then(sample => {
        console.log(sample);
        res.json(sample);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

My service file function in the backend side is like below:

```
async function create(sampleParam) {
    
    const sample = new Sample(sampleParam);
    // save sample
    const saved = await sample.save();
    const created = await Sample.findOne({_id: saved._id});
    console.log(created);
    return await created;
}
```

Besides, both in backend side the two console log function present the same result in the console like this below, which implies that my backend successfully received the data from the frontend:

```
{
  _id: 64a8a8e9903039edb52ccc4c,
  productName: 'Vial 2ml(US) Type1',
  OracleItemNum: 8110000008,
  batchSize: 823248,
  numCntrRecv: 11,
  aqlLevel: 'II',
  createdDate: 2023-07-08T00:08:09.288Z,
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: 64a8a8e9903039edb52ccc4c,
  productName: 'Vial 2ml(US) Type1',
  OracleItemNum: 8110000008,
  batchSize: 823248,
  numCntrRecv: 11,
  aqlLevel: 'II',
  createdDate: 2023-07-08T00:08:09.288Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The question is I can't received it from the response of the frontend side.
Please help me with the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting back is what the fetch Api returned at the end of the day not the data you're expecting. You can try out async and await to resolve your fetch request.

```js
async function addNewSample(sample){
    try {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{ 
            ...authHeader(),
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(sample)
      };
      const response = await fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/samples/newAdd`, requestOptions);
      if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("network error");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      // handle error how you want
    }
}
```

Comment: After following your suggestion and updating my code, I got an error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined```

Comment: my bad add await to the response.json() too. I've updated the code

Comment: Still pop up the same error...

Comment: Also make sure your code support asyn and await. you can use babel and webpack for you set up. That's the issue here.

Comment: Or to keep things simple you can add these scripts.<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/3.31.1/minified.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.11/runtime.min.js"></script> to the body tag of your html. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is as simple as changing.

```
.then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```

to:

```
.then((response) => response.body);
```

And then probably you'll want to parse that:

```
.then((response) => JSON.parse(response.body));
```

Now the `addNewSample` function should return a JSON object representation of the server response body.

Comment: First, thanks for your help! However, After I follow your suggestion to update my code, it shows up an error like this: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Rea"... is not valid JSON```

Comment: I think it is because the body is a ReadableStream not a object that can be transformed to JSON.

Comment: That sound likely. Try something like `response.body.getReader().read()`. Maybe that works, or maybe you'll nee to unwrap the Promise produced by `read`.
There is likely a convenience function that you can use that skips all this and just gives you the plaintext body, but this can work too.

Comment: Still not the correct result... It return things like this below: ```[[Prototype]]: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object```

Comment: When I open these Object above through Developer Tools, each are not return me the data that I expected from backend.